# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding with jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a server side object in my MVC code that looks like this:

```
class Person
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public IList<Friend> Friends { get; set; } 
}

class Friend
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

From the jQuery client, I am making an ajax request and sending the following data (line breaks introduced for readability):

```
var personId = $(...
var personName = $(...

var friends = []; // array of associative arrays

for (var i = 0; i < _friends.length; i++) // _friends is is a global array object and is different from friends below
{
  var friendId = $(...
  var friendName = $(...)

  friends[i] = { 'Id' : friendId, 'Name' : friendName };
}
```

... and so on to get values into variables

Please observe that I am sending what should go into `Person.Friends`, the `IList<T>` as a JavaScript array where each element of the array is an associative list that has properties just like the server side `Friend` class.

Here's my ajax request:

```
$.ajax('/Strings/JsonCreateNew', 
  { 
    cache: false, async: false, type: 'POST', 
    data: { 
        'Id' : personId, 
        'Name' : personName, 
        'Friends' : friends}, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    error: SaveNewFriendClientSideHandler.OnError, 
    success: SaveNewFriendClientSideHandler.OnSuccess 
  });
```

In my controller, as long as I have a `FormCollection` to receive the data, I get all my data, but I'd like to bind to the strongly typed Person object, so if I change my controller definition from:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonCreateNew(FromCollection person)
{
  // I get all the data in the person.AllKeys property
  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonCreateNew(Person person)
{
  // the default ASP.NET MVC model binder isn't able to bind to this
  // in fact, the routing module does not even route the request to this
  // action, so this action never gets fired.
  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

I still do get all my data but I am really still concerned about the `IList<Friend>`.

It is received in the `Person` object as an array that has the correct number of `Friends` objects with the right property names (`Name` and `Id`) but the values of both the properties of each `Friend` object are `null` or 0, i.e. not initialized even when there are values being sent by the client.

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

There is a bug in MVC they refuse to fix that if the colection property name begins with the type name it does not bind. 
Change

```
    public IList<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
```

To:

```
    public IList<Friend> Biscuits { get; set; }
```

just temporary. It will work.

Comment: Cool! That sounds nice. I'll give that a try and post back. :-)

Comment: Would renaming it MyFriends work? That would change it enough such that the property no longer **started** with the type name...

Comment: I don't remember if it is the start or the end. But try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the content type: `contentType: "application/json"`. @MohammadRB solution contains it, but it should work even if you don't stringify the post data.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will work:

```
var p = { 'Id' : personId, 'Name' : personName, 'Friends' : friends };
$.ajax('/Strings/JsonCreateNew', 
  { 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: JSON.Stringify({ person : p }), 
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType: 'json', 
    error: SaveNewFriendClientSideHandler.OnError, 
    success: SaveNewFriendClientSideHandler.OnSuccess 
  });
```

Also i prefer IEnumerable<> instead of IList<> if you only want iterate over them

**Edit**
Test case :

```
var friends = new Array();
friends.push({ Id: "1", Name: "A" });
friends.push({ Id: "2", Name: "B" });
var p = { 'Id': 5, 'Name': "Mohammad", 'Friends': friends };

$(document).ready(function () {

  $.ajax('/Home/JsonCreateNew',
  {
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({ person: p }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function () { alert("f"); },
      success: function () { alert("s"); }
  });

});
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all. In fact, that even broke the sending of the ajax request.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 I add a test and it work and i get person object in serverside action

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 You must add 'contentType: "application/json"' and 'JSON.stringify()' to your ajax request, when i delete them, i also receive null values on server

Comment: For me, the console reports *JSON.Stringify is not a function*. Is there something I have to include to get the JSON object?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 What browser are you using? (are you using lower case of s in stringify. it may be a typo mistake)

Comment: I was stupid. Thanks, I figured that wrong capitalization out when I posted my last comment. Thanks much. However, now even though the JSON.stringify function works, the data received at the server end is still an empty object, whether I receive a `FormCollection` or a `Person` object.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Sorry i can't figure out your problem. If you collect your data from form, why don't you use serialize method on your form?

Comment: Maybe this worked in 2013... If you want a working sample in 2020 check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947968/2484903