# Unable to cast object of type Person to type PersonViewModel

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to send a form array of data my server but it not binding correctly.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public List<Person> Persons {get; set}
}

public class Person{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
   
// view model that wil render all the partial view models showing all the people 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id="people-form" autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    <div class="container">
       @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Persons.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                <label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Persons[i].FirstName)
                </label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>  
}

// ajax used to post, trying to serialize it as an array but still when it hits my action it is not binding.
return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'SavePeople',
    data: $('#people-form').serializeArray(),
}).done(function (response) {

}).fail(function (err) {
    
});

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SavePeople(PersonViewModel vm /* this comes in as null */)
{

}
```

The data getting sent looks like `Persons[0].FirstName: 41441` but for some reason it is trying to bind it directly into the PersonViewModel instead of adding it to the Persons Collection.

Comment: btw you should send something like { persons: [ firstName: 'test']}

Comment: There is no json sent really, I am serializing the entire form which produces Persons%5B0%5D.FirstName=55353 if this was not in a collection it would bind but being a collection is causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this suffers from the same bug identified in [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding with jQuery ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299008/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-with-jquery-ajax-request)

> There is a bug in MVC they refuse to fix that if the colection property name begins with the type name it does not bind.

Try changing:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public List<Person> Persons {get; set}
}
```

To:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public List<Person> People {get; set}
}
```

Try this; if you're still having trouble post below and I'll assist.

Comment: Hey, it seems to still not be working. I changed my code to reflect your changes buts till null in the binding. The data being sent now looks like Persons[0].FirstName

Comment: Sounds like you also need to change in the view - Model.People instead of Model.Persons

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure your ajax is working.

```
return $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: DeploymentPath + '/ControllerName/ActionName',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "parameterName": _input})
});
```

Variable References to your project

- DeploymentPath : url to your project
- ControllerName : controller name of your SavePeople() function
- ActionName: **SavePeople**
- parameterName: **vm**
- _input: your Person objects

Once, your ajax function is able to execute, you can directly access the value in your **SavePeople** action, using `vm.Persons` - which is a List.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you haven't customized serialization settings and model is `@model HomeController.PersonViewModel`. The following expresssion works

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model.Persons[i].FirstName)
```

if nothing works just use IFormCollection and parse values manually or for debugging the specific issue in [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

```
public JsonResult SavePeople(IFormCollection vm)
```